# Как создать визуальное редактирование массива настроек?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Стоит задача создать настройки для CMS. Почитав статью по сравнению [способов настройки](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112402/) решил, что самым лучшим вариантом для моей задачи в плане гибкости и скорости подойдут массивы.

Но вот есть вопрос: как визуально редактировать подобный массив?
Допустим, имеем массив:

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
    'siteName' => "Site Name",
    'api_id' => '3470411',
    'api_token' => 'c83c2d6112d9d0de1e9930b5083c29b9'
];
```

Пока только такой вариант в голову лезет, но он не гибкий, и мне кажется вовсе неверен:

```
$config_field = '<?
    $config = [
    "adminEmail" => "'.$_POST['adminEmail'].'",
    "supportEmail" => "'.$_POST['supportEmail'].'",,
    // other...
    ];

    ?>';
file_put_contents('settings.php', $config_field);
```

Буду рад Вашей помощи.

Comment: Почитайте про [var_export](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-export.php)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону JSON, он приятен, читаем, общепринят, а главное - нативно парсится в PHP через [json_encode](http://php.net/json-encode) / [json_decode](http://php.net/json-decode)

Суть сводится к хранению массива из пар "параметр":"значение". Если записать их через запятую и обрамить фигурными скобками - будет JSON. Все просто

Ваш пример через розовые очки JSON:

```
<?php

$settings = [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
    'siteName' => "Site Name",
    'api_id' => '3470411',
    'api_token' => 'c83c2d6112d9d0de1e9930b5083c29b9'
];

$string = json_encode($settings);
print_r($string);

print '<hr>';

$settings = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($settings);

?>
```

Пример выводит следующее (первый `print_r`, я добавил переносы строк для читаемости, на самом деле это одна строка сплошная):

```
{
"adminEmail":"admin@example.com",
"supportEmail":"support@example.com",
"user.passwordResetTokenExpire":3600,
"siteName":"Site Name",
"api_id":"3470411",
"api_token":"c83c2d6112d9d0de1e9930b5083c29b9"
}
```

Второй `print_r`, тут все понятно, получили обратно наш массив:

```
Array
(
    [adminEmail] => admin@example.com
    [supportEmail] => support@example.com
    [user.passwordResetTokenExpire] => 3600
    [siteName] => Site Name
    [api_id] => 3470411
    [api_token] => c83c2d6112d9d0de1e9930b5083c29b9
)
```

Что делать с получившейся строкой JSON - решать вам. Можно хранить в базе, можно в файле, можно отправить другу. В любом случае, вы всегда можете ее распаковать в массив, добавить пару новых параметров, поменять пару старых и сохранить обратно.

Кстати говоря, в JSON вы сможете хранить любую структуру, не обязательно массив. Строго говоря, это не массив, в объект с полями (фигурные скобки). Массив он просто `[1,2,3...]`, с квадратными. И их можно комбинировать как угодно, массивы объектов, объекты массивов и тд  и тп

Однако, где же редактирование? Вот здесь:

```
// Рисуем форму редактирования
$html = '';
$fields = array();
foreach ($settings as $field => $value) {
    $fields[] = $field;
    $html .= '<label>'.$field.': <input type="text" name="'.$field.'" value="'.$value.'"></label><br>';
}

print '
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="fields" value="'.implode(",", $fields).'">
'.$html.'
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
';
```

Как обрабатывать? Вот например так:

```
// Обрабатываем форму редактирования
$fields = explode(",", $_POST['fields']);
$settings = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $settings[$field] = $_POST[$field];
    }
}
```

Имена сохранены? Да, в отдельном поле формы, через запятую. Значения тоже. Код далек от идеала, но я просто хотел подсказать направление.

Причем тут JSON? Ну не знаю, просто с ним связаны многие приятные воспоминания. Может быть и вам он чем-то приглянется, кто знает )

Comment: и действительно, при чем тут json? автор вопроса ведь явно написал, какой формат хранения конфига ему нужен :)

Comment: Я не теряю надежду подсказать автору способ съэкономить себе нервы и время ) может быть не в этом конкретном случае, но в будущей задаче или через две )

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте форму большую и в каждое поле формы выводите значение типа:

```
<input name="mail" value="<?php echo $config['adminEmail'];?>">
```

И всё. При сохранении обновляете значение в массиве. Только массив всё равно хранить где-то надо, в памяти он же не может быть.

Comment: При сохранении подобного типа сохранится лишь содержимое. Допустим, мы ввели в `adminEmail` "test@mail.com" и файл с настройками(к примеру, settings.php) будет иметь вид "test@mail.com", потеряв всю свою структуру.